# how to calculate time difference in solaris

Tags: solaris

I have a process running in my server which user might not discard. I want to set a script which can calculate time difference and kill this automatically. Can anybody help me to calculate time difference between 2 dates in solaris?

Answer (score 1):

By a little searching, [this link](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.solaris/how-to-get-the-time-difference-in-a-script/58431) may help.

```
date1=$(/usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{srand();print srand()}')
# ... processing ...
date2=$(/usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{srand();print srand()}')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have in a script that records how long it was running by computing the difference between start and end times:

```
START="$(perl -e 'print time')"
  [... body of script ...]
perl -e '$runtime = time - $ARGV[0];
         printf("Runtime: %d:%02d\n", $runtime/3600, ($runtime%3600)/60); ' \
        "${START}"
```