# How to find difference between 2 dates in Korn shell?

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, ksh

I don't seem to find this anywhere... I have two date/time using *`YYYYmmddHHMMSS`*, like this:

```
D1=20140603132050
D2=20140604114020
```

I need to find the difference between them in hours.

- I'm using korn shell;
- I have GNU date;

Any clue?

Comment: What you want to see?

Comment: @realspirituals: I want to see "The difference between D1 and D2 is X hours."

Comment: @fedorqui: For some strange reason, GNU date doesn't recognize the "-d" parameter...

Comment: Oh in Solaris there is no `-d` in date. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsolaris%5D+date shows some approaches, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471585/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-solaris looks helpful.

Comment: This would be easier in a language like Perl or Tcl. what's `perl --version` and/or `echo 'puts [info patchlevel]' | tclsh`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent-ish Perl, you can do:

```
diff_hrs=$(
    printf "%s\n" "$D1" "$D2" | 
    perl -MTime::Piece -e '
        ($t1, $t2) = map {chomp; Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")} <>; 
        print +($t2-$t1)/3600, "\n"
    '
)
```